# Loading a big RData File

Tags: r, load, rdata

I can't load a RData file, I get the following error message

```
> load("GPL570_matrix.Rdata")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.9 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Reached total allocation of 5941Mb: see help(memory.size) 
2: Reached total allocation of 5941Mb: see help(memory.size) 
3: Reached total allocation of 5941Mb: see help(memory.size) 
4: Reached total allocation of 5941Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I tried to increase the memory limit using

```
memory.limit(size=11264)
```

But R ends up crashing. Here's my session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.14.2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is the file? How many bytes exactly? Did you create it or did you get it from somewhere else? Maybe you just don't have enough memory on your computer to read it? When you say 'R ends up crashing', is that after setting the memory limit *and* trying to read the file? All I got is questions, all you want is an answer...

Comment: In addition, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: I got it from someone else, it's a matrix with gene expression data (~10,000 genes and ~57,000 samples). I have an Intel Core i5 with 6 GB in RAM.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. No way is that computer reading that dataset.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. My session is aborted before I can see any other error message, actually.

I'm trying to load a RData file with 63mb. I also run an Intel Core i5 @ 3.40GHz and 8GB RAM. Is it not enough?

Comment: Load is not loading, please change the tag load to loading.

Comment: Did you try using SparkR loadDF function?